# Extracting time from middle of string in R when string changes c

Tags: r, extract, strsplit

I have a dataset containing training data for multiple athletes on different days/times. One column contains the date and start time of the session. I only wish to keep the start time in this column i.e. i want to remove "2020/01/05" and "UTC". How to I remove everything before and after the time (there are 4 million rows with varying dates/times).

```
 start.time
1 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 
2 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 
3 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 
4 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 
5 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 
6 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC
```

Sorry this has probably already been answered somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this :

1) Using regex

```
df$time <- sub('.*\\s+(.*) UTC', '\\1', df$start.time)
df
#               start.time     time
#1 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
#2 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
#3 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
#4 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
#5 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
#6 2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC 21:30:04
```

Here, we capture everything between whitespace and `"UTC"`. `\\1` is used as a backreference to capture the extracted value.

---

2) Convert to `POSIXct` and then `format`

This can be done in base R :

```
format(as.POSIXct(df$start.time, format = "%Y/%m/%d %T"), "%T")
```

Or using `lubridate`

```
format(lubridate::ymd_hms(df$start.time), "%T")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(start.time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC", class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I used sub and it worked perfectly but could you please explain how it works? i.e. what do the arguments you entered mean ?(sorry I am new to R)

Comment: @wattss I updated the answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
format(anytime(df$start.time), "%T")
```

---

Or with `as.ITime`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(df$start.time)
#[1] "21:30:04" "21:30:04" "21:30:04" "21:30:04" "21:30:04" "21:30:04"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(start.time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "2020/01/05 21:30:04 UTC", class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```